# Why is the bash_history always coming up the same and not updating using non-login shells?

Tags: bash, command-line

The last few days I've noticed that whenever I shutdown my system (Debian Testing) and fire up a bash session, then press the up arrow key, I get the commands from the first time I cleared the history cache using `history -c`. I'm not sure how this happened, but even if I clear my history again, then press the up arrow, nice it works, but if I start another shell it doesn't (even less whenever I restart or shutdown or log off).

I've tried everything (even deleting the `.bash_history` by hand), so I ran out of ideas.

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
$ /bin/bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.45(1)-release (i486-pc-linux-gnu)
$ echo $HISTFILE
/home/braiam/.bash_history
```

When looking for information to add the question, I ran `ls -l .bash_history` (not to look like a dumb) and found the problem:

```
$ ls -l .bash_history 
-r--------. 1 braiam braiam 59372 Jul 26 20:18 .bash_history
```

But running `chmod +w .bash_history` didn't save the day. Now I wonder how it could end like that...

After deleting the `.bash_history` file now I have no-history. I checked the .bashrc for clues:

```
cat .bashrc | grep -i hist
# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend
# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000
```

---

Following ash's answer, in a non-login (gnome-terminal) shell:

```
braiam@bt:~$ echo abacaba; echo $$
abacaba
15372
braiam@bt:~$
```

Then fired up another non-login shell:

```
braiam@bt:~$ strace -o e -s 256 -p 15372
Process 15372 attached - interrupt to quit
```

Went back to the first shell, then type `history -a`:

```
braiam@bt:~$ echo abacaba; echo $$
abacaba
15372
braiam@bt:~$ history -a
braiam@bt:~$
```

In the shell with strace, nothing:

```
braiam@bt:~$ strace -o e -s 256 -p 15372
Process 15372 attached - interrupt to quit
```

Here I was almost without hope, so I decided to look at strace manual and found that `-o` is to dump the result to a file, so `cat e` resturn this:

```
cat e
read(0, "\33", 1)                       = 1
read(0, "[", 1)                         = 1
read(0, "A", 1)                         = 1
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [INT], [], 8) = 0
write(2, "history -w", 10)              = 10
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
read(0, "\33", 1)                       = 1
read(0, "[", 1)                         = 1
read(0, "A", 1)                         = 1
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [INT], [], 8) = 0
write(2, "\10a", 2)                     = 2
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
read(0, "\r", 1)                        = 1
write(2, "\n", 1)                       = 1
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [INT], [], 8) = 0
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or TCSETSW, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x80a0e30, [], 0}, {0x80e9d00, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {SIG_IGN, [], 0}, {SIG_IGN, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {SIG_IGN, [], 0}, {SIG_IGN, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {0x80a1080, [HUP INT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM XCPU XFSZ VTALRM SYS], 0}, {0x80e9d00, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {SIG_IGN, [], 0}, {SIG_IGN, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTOU, {SIG_IGN, [], 0}, {SIG_IGN, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTIN, {SIG_IGN, [], 0}, {SIG_IGN, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGWINCH, {0x80a09e0, [], 0}, {0x80e9550, [], SA_RESTART}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x80a0e30, [], 0}, {0x80a0e30, [], 0}, 8) = 0
time(NULL)                              = 1378047084
stat64("/home/braiam/.bash_history", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=44, ...}) = 0
open("/home/braiam/.bash_history", O_WRONLY|O_APPEND|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
write(3, "history -w\nhistory -a\n", 22) = 22
close(3)                                = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x80a0e30, [], 0}, {0x80a0e30, [], 0}, 8) = 0
time(NULL)                              = 1378047084
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD TSTP TTIN TTOU], [], 8) = 0
ioctl(255, TIOCSPGRP, [15372])          = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x80a0e30, [], 0}, {0x80a0e30, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [INT], [], 8) = 0
ioctl(0, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=24, ws_col=80, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
ioctl(0, TIOCSWINSZ, {ws_row=24, ws_col=80, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or TCSETSW, {B38400 opost isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [INT QUIT ALRM TERM TSTP TTIN TTOU], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x80e9d00, [], 0}, {0x80a0e30, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {0x80e9d00, [], 0}, {SIG_IGN, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {SIG_IGN, [], 0}, {0x80e9d00, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {0x80e9d00, [], 0}, {SIG_IGN, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {SIG_IGN, [], 0}, {0x80e9d00, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {0x80e9d00, [], 0}, {0x80a1080, [HUP INT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM XCPU XFSZ VTALRM SYS], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {0x80e9d00, [], 0}, {SIG_IGN, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {SIG_IGN, [], 0}, {0x80e9d00, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTOU, {0x80e9d00, [], 0}, {SIG_IGN, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTOU, {SIG_IGN, [], 0}, {0x80e9d00, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTIN, {0x80e9d00, [], 0}, {SIG_IGN, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTIN, {SIG_IGN, [], 0}, {0x80e9d00, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGWINCH, {0x80e9550, [], SA_RESTART}, {0x80a09e0, [], 0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [INT], [], 8) = 0
write(2, "\33]0;braiam@bt: ~\7\33[01;31mbraiam@bt\33[00m:\33[01;34m~\33[00m$ ", 56) = 56
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
read(0,  <unfinished ...>
```

So, according to this, there is not problem. Then, I open another non-login shell, and no joy. The history isn't loaded. A `cat .bash_history` reveals that the file was indeed filled but the non-login shell doesn't take it.

Now, I tried both `strace -o /tmp/e -s 512 bash` [here](http://pastebin.com/NdUAAtcG) (too long for character limit) and `strace -o /tmp/e -s 512 gnome-terminal` [here](http://pastebin.com/pHjmDfrz) (both from pastebin.com, sorry). [Here](http://pastebin.com/EQdzbcVx) with the original settings (minus the -w permission on .bash_history).

I tried login next, Ctrl + Alt + F1, logged in, pressed the up arrow, crossed fingers and it worked! But, that still leave me with the interrogant, why doesn't the non-login shell loads the history?

Comment: Try setting the environment variable `HISTFILESIZE=0` in your .bash_profile.

Comment: The behavior of those variables are described in the bash man page if you want to more details :)

Comment: Are the shell sessions being closed normally - either through the `exit` or `logout` commands, pressing `ctrl-d`, or the sighup signal?  If not, the shell won't write the updated history.

Comment: @ash of course. I did logout properly, or closed the gnome terminal.

Comment: You may be interested in [this](http://superuser.com/q/575479/151431) discussion.

Comment: @terdon no, in my case my bash_history file, doesn't read any new command, whenever I press Ctrl - D or logout.

Comment: @Braiam I know, that's why I only posted a comment. I was just thinking that that question thread has a lot of relevant information and some useful links that might help you out.

Answer (score 3):

you tried `history -c && history -w` ?

`history -c` clear the cache of history function and `history -w` write the commands on the cache of history function (nothing) in .bash_history.

Another option is clear the bash history `/dev/null > ~/.bash_history` and link `~/.bash_history` to `/dev/null`: `ln -sf /dev/null ~/.bash_history`

if you don't want to save the commands of the current shell session, you must run `history -r` to reset the history cache to its initial state (before starting session). Then you log out and the commands on history cache (the same as before starting shell session) will be written in `.bash_history`

Comment: Umm... I like my history, what I don't like is that it doesn't remembers any of the recent commands that I fire up.

Comment: I don't quite get that.  Do you mean the same terminal window or a different one?

Comment: @MichaelDurrant every terminal, none of them remembers what my last commands were.

Comment: This worked. Is it intended behavior that `history -c` clears history in the current window only?

Answer (score 3):

One reason this could happen is that the shells are not exitting normally, or you're looking for updates when the shells are still running.

To test this scenario, try `history -a` after some unique command, like `echo abacaba` on a running shell and then start a new shell.  If the new shell gets the updates from the first, then writing and reading the history file is working.  However, if that doesn't work, something else is wrong, and I would personally use `strace` in an attempt to diagnose.

Another thing to check is that the HOME variable has not changed and is set to the same path as set in the `passwd` file for the user.

**Using strace to diagnose**

- in a shell, `echo abacaba; echo $$`
- in another shell, `strace -o e -s 256 -p $PID`, where `$PID` = `$$` output from the first shell
- in the first shell, `history -a`
- stop the strace and look through it for the processing of `history -a`; there should be open() and write() calls.

**Non-Interactive Shells**

It's odd that the non-interactive shells are not getting the shell history, but this could be explained by a number of things.  More diagnostics will help.

Strace can again be used to help on that end, if the startup of the non-interactive shells can be modified to insert strace.  For example, the following shows a shell startup command modified to use strace:

```
bash /home/jack/bin/jacks_script
strace -f -o /tmp/e -s 512 bash /home/jack/bin/jacks_script
```

Of course, if more than one of these runs at a time, `/tmp/e` will get overwritten.

Using `grep open /tmp/e`, the full path to the bash_history file should show up if the shell is loaded it.  So, this command allows two checks: (1) that a history file is being opened and read, and (2) that the path to the history file is as-expected.

**Without strace**

Verify the shell has the `history` option set (`set -o history` for bash).

One thing that is unclear is just when `HISTFILE` is checked by the shell.  For example, if it's set in the `.bash_profile`, I'm not sure whether it will take affect for the reading of shell history because it's after the shell starts, but before the first command-prompt is given to the user.

Comment: Ran the commands as you suggested, see my question for update.

Comment: Got it.  That helped.  It would also help to see how the shells are being started.  I'm curious why you refer to some as non-interactive shells; that might lead to an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm messing with myself, instead non-interactive is *non-login* (gnome-terminal) which remembers/write to the history files.

Comment: gnome-terminal; I've never used it; I'm an xterm user myself.  I'll check it out.

Comment: It worked; not really surprised.  Can you run a gnome-terminal by hand, by just running it from a shell (even out of another gnome-terminal)?  If so, and the problem persists that way, `strace -o /tmp/e -s 512 gnome-terminal` will help.

Comment: done, check my last edit

Comment: Apologies, I should have included the `-f` option on the gnome-terminal trace.  I'll update the answer and then check the `bash` trace posted.

Comment: By the way, please be careful about posting these traces - they do contain hints that could be used by someone to attack your system.  Even the exact username and path to home directory could help.

Comment: Something is very odd in the bash trace given.  The shell opens the history file `open("...", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3`, reads the entire contents, then opens it again for writing, truncating it to 0 bytes: `open("...", O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE) = 3`.   With nothing significant in-between.  Could there be `history` commands in an rc script, such as `.bashrc`?

Comment: I used `HISTFILESIZE=0` and `PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'` in the first strace. Now I reverted it to original settings (as you can see in the question), or there is something else I sould look for?

Comment: Hmm, the new trace with original settings is exactly the same as the old trace.  HISTFILESIZE=0 could certainly explain the results seen.  That will prevent any history from going into the file.

Comment: Another thing to try: use `-x` on the shell which will cause it to output every command as it executes it.  Then look for any commands with `hist` or `HIST` in the name.  Like this `bash -x mycommand 2>trace.out; grep -i hist trace.out`.

Comment: Ok, I don't know what solved it... I didn't had the HISTFILESIZE=0 at the start of the question, and only set it up after reading a link in terdon comment above. Now, if I use Ctrl+D, close the terminal, whatever, it works... it is very weird. If you could resume all the suggestion that you commented, it would be the best.

Comment: OK - I'm always nervous when a problem "magically disappears".  Perhaps if you run for a while you'll find the problems occurs and you know exactly why thanks to this effort.  If it happens again and you can't figure it out, give a shout again.

Answer (score 1):

What I ended doing was setting `HISTFILESIZE` to 0 in the `.bashrc` file, as [Drav Sloan](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/44072/drav-sloan) said in comments.

```
[...]
HISTFILESIZE=0
[...]
```

Comment: Sadly, that doesn't fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can just unset `$HISTFILE` (which contains the path to the history file), which won't affect your ability to use history in the current session:

```
unset HISTFILE
```

Comment: I want the history, just that it is persistent and the new commands doesn't get recorded.